# ActionScripts 3 check current file and folder exsist

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, animate-cc

How to get **current path** of a compiled **AIR** executable application and check a **file** and **folder** exist in same location?

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work:

```
var File1:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('APPAR-NC.exe');
if (File1.exists) 
{
    trace("The file exists.");
} 
else 
{
    trace("The file does not exists.")
};
```

Comment: What part of this code is wrong!?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Does it trace the wrong case? Or it doesn't trace at all while other traces work fine?

Comment: Please clearly define your problem, present your efforts and tries, and the failure/outcome. So we can have an idea what may be the problem and offer some solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small change in your code.

```
        var File1:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("APPAR-NC.exe");
        if (File1.exists)
        {
            if(File1.isDirectory)
                trace("The folder exists.");
            else
                trace("The file exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            trace("The file does not exists.")
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html

```
// The folder where your app is installed to.
File.applicationDirectory:File

// The same result as above.
new File("app://")

// The same folder as a system path string.
File.applicationDirectory.nativePath:String

// Returns true if file/folder, represented by the File object, exists.
File.exists:Boolean

// Returns true if the path, represented by the File object, is a folder rather than a file.
File.isDirectory:Boolean
```

Comment: I saw documentation, but if you could write some code it was better.